# Highlight current item in inner post menu in WordPress

Tags: menu, highlight

WordPress has a built in feature that assigns the class “current-menu-item” to the current navigation item.

Nevertheless, that feature only works for contextual menus; and not for the ones inside the post content.

You can see in [this page](http://miguelvarea.dinamicaweb.net/slider-grafika/) that the first level parent item OBRAS is highlighted, but not the third level child GRÁFIKA located left in the inner page menu.

Looking for a method to accomplish this highlight feature in the inner menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question based on 2 facts:

– The menu is created by WordPress.

– The plugin; all it does is generate a shortcut to insert the menu inside the post.

So the question is not Theme related, and not plugin related. It´s WordPress related.

Nevertheless, I asked the Theme developer and the Plugin developer, without response.

In addition, no answer from WordPress.Org Forum. All they say is “ask the theme or plugin developer”.

Therefore, once I found a solution, not the ideal one but at least one that will allow the highlight effect without any core modification, I felt I had to post it here:

I used Wordpress Add Custom CSS plugin to add css per each page.

Then I added the individual code for the [first inner menu item](http://miguelvarea.dinamicaweb.net/slider-grafika/) and it worked:

```
li#menu-item-981 a {    
  color: #FEBF46 !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 0 #FEBF46;
}
```

And that was it; not an ideal automatic solution, but a simple and clean one.

Thanks for your attention.